# Pullback of a 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ be a parametrisation of a manifold $M$.

Given the form $\displaystyle \omega = \sum_{j=1}^N w^j\mathrm{d}x_j$ where $f_j\in C^\infty (M)$.

The pullback is defined by $\displaystyle f^*\omega =\sum_{j=1}^N (w^j\circ f)\mathrm{d}f_j$

It holds true that $f^*\omega (X)(x)=\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$ where $X$ is a smooth vector field.

I can not reproduce this equivalence. I don't even see the term $\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$ well defined, since $f'(x)$ must be a $N\times n$ matrix.

If I start with the left side I get

$\displaystyle  f^*\omega (X)(x)=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^N (w^j\circ f)(x)a_i(x)\frac{\partial f_j(x)}{\partial x_i}$

I hope at least this is correct.

Comment: what is $a_i(x)$?

Comment: The term $\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$ is well-defined.  As you say, $f'(x)$ is an $N \times n$ matrix.  This matrix is multiplied by the (column) vector $X_x$, which has $n$ components (remember that the vector field $X$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, not $\mathbb{R}^N$).  The result, $f'(x)X_x$, is a (column) vector with $N$ components.

Comment: Then I don't really understand how $f^*\omega(x) = \omega_{f(x)}(f'(x))$, e.g. not evaluated at a vector field, is defined. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: A $1$-form takes vectors as inputs and produces real numbers as outputs.  The $1$-form $f^*\omega(x) = \omega_{f(x)}(f'(x))$ takes the vector $X_x$ as input and produces the number $\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$ as an output.  Separately: You still have not specified what $a_i(x)$ is in your last formula.

Comment: But $f'(x)$ is not a vector. My definition never involved vectors in the first place. Could you show an example of $w_{f(x)}(f'(x))$? The $a_i(x)$ are the coefficients of a tangential vector $X=\sum_{i=1}a_i(x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(x)$.

Comment: I didn't say $f'(x)$ is a vector: I said it was a matrix.  The $1$-form $f^*\omega(x)$ is a function (a rule) which inputs the vector $X_x$ and outputs the number $\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$, where here the $N \times n$ matrix $f'(x)$ is multiplied by the vector $X_x$ and then $\omega_{f(x)}$ is applied to the result.  So, $\omega_{f(x)}(f'(x)X_x)$ just means $\omega_{f(x)} \circ f'(x)X_x$. I don't know how to make that clearer, sorry. But you should edit to include say that $X = \sum a_i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x)$, because that is not obvious to someone reading your post.